# Regex accept special french character between double quote

Tags: .net, regex

I currently use this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9&.""')#*:;<>&`=%?@\}!{(,_+-/$ \[\]\\]+$
```

And I would accept the special characters:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9éèêëËÉÈÊàâÀÂîïÎÏçÇôÔûÛùÙ&`.""')#*:;<>&=%?@\}!{(,_+-/$ \[\]\\]+
```

only if the user has entered the quote and when it will again grabbed the quote again, the application will accept the first regex.

We should accept :

- hello "été" ddd
- "été" hello
- "été"
- hello

But we do not accept :

- été
- éte "aaa"
- "aaa" été

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9&.')#*:;<>&`=%?@\}!{(,_+-/$ \[\]\\]+|"[a-zA-Z0-9éèêëËÉÈÊàâÀÂîïÎÏçÇôÔûÛùÙ&`.')#*:;<>&=%?@\}!{(,_+-/$ \[\]\\]+")+$
```

This will match any of the first set of characters (basic Latin letters, digits various symbols) or a sequence of the second set of characters (French letters, etc.) enclosed in quotes. You can simplify this a bit using the case [`IgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) option:

```
^(?:[a-z0-9&.')#*:;<>&`=%?@\}!{(,_+-/$ \[\]\\]+|"[a-z0-9éèêëàâîïçôûù&`.')#*:;<>&=%?@\}!{(,_+-/$ \[\]\\]+")+$
```

You can test it [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gim&regex=%5E%28?%3a%5Ba-z0-9&.%27%29#%2a%3a;%3C%3E&%60=%25?@%5C%7D!%7B%28,_%2b-/%24%20%5C%5B%5C%5D%5C%5C%5D%2b%7C%22%5Ba-z0-9%C3%A9%C3%A8%C3%AA%C3%AB%C3%A0%C3%A2%C3%AE%C3%AF%C3%A7%C3%B4%C3%BB%C3%B9&%60.%27%29#%2a%3a;%3C%3E&=%25?@%5C%7D!%7B%28,_%2b-/%24%20%5C%5B%5C%5D%5C%5C%5D%2b%22%29%2b%24&input=hello%20%22%C3%A9t%C3%A9%22%20ddd%0A%22%C3%A9t%C3%A9%22%20hello%0A%22%C3%A9t%C3%A9%22%0Ahello%0A%0A%C3%A9t%C3%A9%0A%C3%A9te%20%22aaa%22%0A%22aaa%22%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9).

---

**Update** It appears you want an expression that will match a partial input, e.g. `hello "é` should be accepted. In general this is very difficult to and I'd usually recommend using two patterns—one for validating complete input and one for validating partial input.

To support partial input I'd use this:

```
^(?:[a-z0-9&.')#*:;<>&`=%?@\}!{(,_+-/$ \[\]\\]*|"[a-z0-9éèêëàâîïçôûù&`.')#*:;<>&=%?@\}!{(,_+-/$ \[\]\\]*(?:"|$))+$
```

Notice that I replaced the trailing `"` with a `"|$`, so it can the quoted text can either be closed, or terminated by the end of the string. But if you want to ensure that the quoted text is closed once they have finished inputting text, you still have to use the full pattern.

Comment: Your regex works almost perfectly.

I use this regex to validade every user and I KeyPress not accept an invalid value.

Your Regex accept everything fine. Except when I get to enter the quotes she rejects the text takes

Ex: Hello "(not work)

I change to this one :
^(?i)(?:[a-z0-9&.')#*:;<>&`=%?@\}!{(,_+-/$ \[\]\\]+|"|"[a-z0-9éèêëàâîïçôûù&`.')#*:;<>&=%?@\}!{(,_+-/$ \[\]\\]+|"[a-z0-9éèêëàâîïçôûù&`.')#*:;<>&=%?@\}!{(,_+-/$ \[\]\\]+")+$

But not my regex accept all character after the first quote are encounted
Ex: hello "été" eté

But hello "été" supporse to works.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's works great! For my personal knowledge, why you replace the "+" characters by "*" ?

Comment: @user2704902 Because you also need to accept an open section quoted text that contains no characters, e.g. `hello "`. If you'd like to ensure that it can't be immediately closed, e.g. `hello ""`, you'd have to use something like `[...]+|"$|"[...]+("|$)`.

Comment: If I use the string PANEL 2/4C 60A 1PH 3W 120/240V MAIN LUGS SURFACE NEMA-1 â the regex validation freeze (regex.ismatch), do know why? This is happen only with a long string like this.

Comment: @user2704902 See note on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx): "*Nesting quantifiers (for example, as the regular expression pattern `(a*)*` does) can increase the number of comparisons that the regular expression engine must perform, as an exponential function of the number of characters in the input string.*". This may be better suited for a different SO question, but I recommend simplifying your pattern to `"(?:X*|"Y*(?:"|$))+"` for further testing (these huge character classes are a bit of a pain).

Comment: @user2704902 If you're willing to relax your requirements a bit and allow only a single quoted substring you can get rid of the nested qualifiers. e.g. `^X*(""Y*(""|$))?X*$` works pretty quickly even for long strings.

Comment: thanks for your help, you solution work fine. And In this case, I not needs nested validation.